# How to automate mobile validation box in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to automate mobile number validation box but after entering mobile number and trying to focus on validation triangle button, It's throwing error.

Code:

```
 #Mobile
           Set Focus To Element    xpath://*[@placeholder='Mobile Number']
           Input Text    xpath://*[@placeholder='Mobile Number']             8178089068
            Sleep   2s
Scroll Element Into View  xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[7]/div/a/img

#Set Focus To Element    xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[7]/div/a/img

Wait Until Element Is Visible  xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[7]/div/a/img

Click Element  xpath:/html/body/ion-modal/app-add-customer-popup/ion-content/div/div/div/form/div/div/div[7]/div/a/img
```

Error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <img _ngcontent-uqp-c191="" src="assets/imgs/verification_icon.svg" aria-hidden="true" class="check-icon" style="color: green;"> is not clickable at point (1017, 320). Other element would receive the click: <img _ngcontent-uqp-c191="" src="assets/imgs/verification_icon.svg" aria-hidden="true" class="check-icon" style="color: green;">
```

[Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4NWZ.png)

[Source of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lvv1h.png)

Comment: Use ``` at the start and end of your code and error